# how to give a kendo ui autocomplete widget with multiple values, the css functionality of a kendo ui multiselect widget

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete, kendo-multiselect

I am wondering if there's an easy way to have the multiselect widget's css functionality shown in this demo

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/multiselect/index.html

applied to an autocomplete widget.

Comment: Why not using multiselect? What are you looking from autocomplete that you miss in multiselect?

Comment: i chose autocomplete widgets for those input fields that are bound to a datasource with many data items (several thousands). So in this case the user types the first (i.e.) 3 letters and the datasource is filtered according to his input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only reason for using `autocomplete` is that the list of values is huge and you want to do server side filtering ([`serverFiltering`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverFiltering)) with a `multiselect` widget as well. You just need to define `serverFiltering` as `true`.

Example:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url : "getData.php"
        }
    },
    serverFiltering: true
});

$("#items").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataValueField: "name",
    dataTextField : "name",
    dataSource    : ds
});
```

You will receive a some additional parameters saying what the user has typed so far and you server can return only the data that meets the condition.

This JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/rpDuL/) tries to show you how it works. You can start typing a country name and see that it actually filters the data. Since this is just JavaScript I've simulated server filtering implementing a `read` function that `grep`s the data for those records meeting the condition.

Comment: i apologize for not checking really carefully the multiselect documentation. thanks a lot. One more question, for the record: why someone choose multi-autocomplete functionality instead of multiselect? What more does it offer (except from the different css functionality)?

Comment: Not sure maybe some historical question, first there was AutoComplete, then AutoComplete with multiple options and finally MultiSelect. Also, typically (not sure if mandatory) AutoComplete is mapped in an HTML `input` and MultiSelect in `select`